# Check if object is Null in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I can't check if an imported value from SQL to Excel is Null. In debug mode I can se that the assigned value is Null, i.e. not the string "Null". Have tried *is Nothing* as in my code example, but also *isEmpty* and *= "Null"*.

It's the line **If dbList(2) Is Nothing Then** in the code below that I'm having trouble with.

How can I check if the recordset is Null?

```
...
Dim CmdSP As New ADODB.Command
CmdSP.CommandType = adCmdText
CmdSP.CommandText = "SELECT FundName, FundId, SRL.Comment FROM XXX SRL ON XXX = XXX ORDER BY FundName ASC"

CmdSP.ActiveConnection = dbConn

Dim dbList As ADODB.Recordset
Set dbList = CmdSP.Execute

Dim row As Integer
row = 1
While Not dbList.EOF
    DataStorage.Range("dsFundsTopLeft")(row, 2) = dbList(0)
    DataStorage.Range("dsFundsTopLeft")(row, 3) = dbList(1)
    If dbList(2) Is Nothing Then
        DataStorage.Range("dsFundsTopLeft")(row, 4) = "No rating"
    Else
        DataStorage.Range("dsFundsTopLeft")(row, 4) = dbList(2)
    End If
    dbList.MoveNext
    row = row + 1
Wend
...
```

Comment: Before `If dbList(2) Is Nothing Then` put a `Debug.Print TypeName(dbList(2))` - what is the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try function `isNull`

```
If isNull(dbList(2)) Then
```

Comment: Feeling stupid now, but the function was not valid when i tried it before. Must have spelled it wrong!